# Issue with C++ code

Tags: c++

I was trying to figure out this task, but so far have been unsuccessful. I think I understand the logic behind it, I just don’t know how to nest loops so it works (if that makes sense). I would very much appreciate your help!

Task:
"Create an application in which a user enters full numbers until they enter number 0 (zero). The application should print out how many even numbers have been entered, how many odd numbers, sum of even numbers and sum of odd numbers, and total sum of numbers."

my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main() {

do {

int input1;
cout << "Type in a number";
cin >> input1;

} while (input1 != 0);

cout << "Type in a number";
cin >> input1;

if (input1 % 2 == 0)
{
 int even = 0;
 while (input1 % 2 == 0 )
  cout << even;
 even++;
}
else
{
 int odd = 0;
 while (odd != 0)
 {

  cout << odd;
  odd++;
 }
}

}

system("pause");
}
```

Note: I did not try to do the third part of the task, since the second one won't work :/ I figured out first part, and I did it with do while loop. Thanks again.

Comment: This algorithm is quite a way off from the intended goal - the best advice would be to read a [good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Also note that `void main` isn't valid C++.

Comment: Just as I thought...this doesn't even compile!

Comment: *I figured out first part, and I did it with do while loop.* That loop in itself is faulty since it basically does nothing. It keeps on inputting the data but does nothing with it and also `input1` is local to that block!

Comment: I think you went astray when you assumed that there would be any nesting of loops – there should only be one. All the processing and bookkeeping goes inside the reading loop. All the output goes after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int oddCount = 0;
int evenCount = 0;
int oddSum = 0;
int evenSum = 0;

int in;
do
{
    std::cout << "Type in a number:";
    std::cin >> in;

    if (0 == in)
        break;

    if ( in % 2 == 0 )
    {
        evenCount++;
        evenSum += in;
    }
    else
    {
        oddCount++;
        oddSum += in;
    }
} while ( true );

std::cout << "Odd count: " << oddCount << std::endl;
std::cout << "Even count: " << evenCount << std::endl;
std::cout << "Odd sum: " << oddSum << std::endl;
std::cout << "Even sum: " << evenSum << std::endl;
std::cout << "Total sum: " << oddSum + evenSum << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int input;
    int total_sum = 0, odd_sum = 0, even_sum = 0;
    int odd_count = 0, even_count = 0;

    do {
        cout << "Type in a number: ";
        cin >> input;

        total_sum += input;

        if (input % 2 == 0)
        {
            even_count++;
            even_sum += input;
        }
        else
        {
            odd_count++;
            odd_sum += input;
        }

    } while (input != 0);

    cout << "Total Sum: " << total_sum << endl;
    cout << "Even sum: " << even_sum << endl;
    cout << "Odd sum: " << odd_sum << endl;
    cout << "Even Count: " << even_count << endl;
    cout << "Odd Count: " << odd_count << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

See how input is declared outside of the loop. if it was inside it, then you essentially create it each time you enter the loop. that would be fine if you did not want to use its values outside of the loop (like in the loops condition).

Also, notice that the values you need to calculate can be updated within that same loop.

Comment: Your are also processing the user input `0`. Due to which you'll have the wrong **even count**.

Comment: @AditiRawat Please quote the part where it says not to process that number. I could not see that, so I figured I can decide how to treat it (after all it is an even number that was entered)

Comment: when you enter 0 total_count++; goes up, but it shouldn't

Comment: @ Yuval Ben-Arie *Create an application in which a user enters full numbers **until** they enter number 0*

Comment: @KillzoneKid says who? I did that intentionally

Comment: @AditiRawat That just says you need to not get more numbers after 0, not what to do with that zero

Comment: @Yuval Ben-Arie you are right, there is no task description to print out total count, but you do it anyway, so yeah you can do whatever you want with it.